# Pre-populate password field in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way to pre-populate a Django form password field so that it display something in the resulting `<input type="password">` html element?

The default behavior seems to be not to display anything when the `MyForm(initial = {'passfield':'something'})` is set.

I need this in order to implement an user edit form. I want to display a random string which if the user doesn't modify I will know that he does not want to change the password. So I don't think there is ANY security issue in what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to set default values for password fields. Consider the case in which someone keeps the password without changing it; the value of the password can be discovered by looking at the HTML for the page.

Comment: Why would you want to prepopulate a password field? This seems like a big security issue.

Comment: Please, I just want to do this. I'm implementing a user edit form and want to display something in the password field. If the user doesn't modify it I won't change the password.

Comment: See my reply below to minism's answer. Thanks for the edit :D

Comment: What if the user doesn't put anything in the password field, then don't change the password?

Comment: Out of the question. It's much more intuitive for the user to see something there.

Comment: Actually, I see more sites leave the password field blank if you don't want to edit it. I'd personally be confused if it's prepopulated.

Comment: I must disagree, of course :). Seeing an empty password field is an invitation to changing it.

Comment: I agree with @dannyroa. Using HTML placeholder you have have a different message like "your new password here". If course its your choice if you want to display the password but I think that majority of web developers will agree that that is not the best approach.

Comment: Ok. Then I disagree with both of you :)). I think your way is a good alternative but I prefer doing it like I want to and am happy that it CAN be done quite easily.

Comment: @AlBundy What if the user wants that exact message text as his password? ;)

Comment: It is a random generated 8 chars string. What's the chance of that!?

Comment: 1 in 1,000,000 chance. But there's still a chance. ;-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems that using the render_value argument works not just for the case listed in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput) and can be used:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    password_field = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = True))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput), Django `PasswordField` does not support initial value. So even when you pass it, it would not render.

You can either subclass the field and make your own password widget which will allow you to do so or you can use HTML5 `placeholder`. HTML5 is much more secure bevause you can display something to the user, but not the password itself.

For HTML5 support, you can use https://github.com/adamcupial/django-html5-forms. Then you can do something like (not exact syntax but something along the lines of):

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    password = forms.PasswordField(..., placeholder="Your password here")
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across similar situation and I did the following:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = PasswordField(label="Password")
```

In the `PasswordField` there is `PasswordInput` field you will need to set `render_value = True` as mentioned above which is by default `False`, then during initialization of `UserForm` I passed initial value for password.

```
UserForm(instance=user, initial={'password1': settings.dummy_password})
```

Now this initial value was predefined in settings file which I compare if the password is changed then update the password else leave the original as is.